# Warning when using MSGarch package to compute multi step VaR

Tags: r

Well here is the code for the parallel loop used to generate Var and it works correctly normally :

```
    cl <- makeCluster(5) #not to overload your computer
    registerDoSNOW(cl) 

    #parallel foreach loop
    N=195

    data_startpoint = 2

    #VaR_matrix = matrix(0,20,max(N))
    VaR_matrix_MS = matrix(0,20,max(N))
    tempMatrix = matrix(0,20,max(N))
    ############################################################

    #VaR_matrix  <- foreach(i = 1:N,.combine = "cbind") %dopar% {
    VaR_matrix_MS  <- foreach(i = 1:N,.combine = "cbind") %dopar% { 
      #tempMatrix[,i] = multi_day_VaR(10067+i-1,11567+i-1)
      tempMatrix[,i] = multi_day_VaR(data_startpoint+i-1,data_startpoint+1500+i-2)
      tempMatrix[,i]
      #Equivalent to finalMatrix = cbind(finalMatrix, tempMatrix)
    }
    #stop cluster
    stopCluster(cl)
    end.time <- Sys.time()
    time.taken <- end.time - start.time
    time.taken
```

And here is the code for the function called inside the loop and its also using some function of the package keblu/MSGARCH and a uses a pre generated data :

```
  multi_day_VaR <- function(est_begin, est_end) {
  library(MSGARCH)
  data_est = All_dataset[c(est_begin:est_end),2]#6years 1500, AIC:  3728.115 
  data_est = as.numeric(as.character(data_est))
  ###################################################################################
  #data_est = All_dataset[c(2:1501),2]#6years 1500, AIC:  3728.115
  ###################################################################################

  ## Example 1: A single-regime model
  #spec <- CreateSpec(variance.spec = list(model = c("sGARCH")),
   #                  distribution.spec = list(distribution = c("norm")))
  #spec <- CreateSpec(variance.spec = list(model = c("sGARCH")),
  #                  distribution.spec = list(distribution = c("sstd")))
  ## Example 2: A MS-GARCH model
  spec <- CreateSpec(variance.spec = list(model = c("gjrGARCH")),
                     distribution.spec = list(distribution = c("sstd")),
                     switch.spec = list(do.mix = FALSE, K = 2))

  #set.seed(123)
  #out.mle = MSGARCH:: FitML(spec = spec, data = data_est)

  #ctr.bay = list(n.burn = 5000L, n.mcmc = 10000L, n.thin = 10L, par0 = out.mle$par)
  ctr.bay = list(n.burn = 5000L, n.mcmc = 10000L, n.thin = 10L)
  set.seed(123)                                                           
  out.bay = MSGARCH::FitMCMC(spec = spec, data = data_est, ctr = ctr.bay)
  #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  #compute the one-step ahead Value-at-Risk and Expected-shortfall out-of-sample
  #Risk(object = out.bay, alpha = c(0.01, 0.05), do.es = FALSE, do.its = FALSE, n.ahead = 250)
  #Risk(object = out.mle, alpha = c(0.01, 0.05), do.es = FALSE, do.its = FALSE, n.ahead = 20)
  #------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  set.seed(123)
  sim = Sim(object = out.bay, n.ahead = 250, n.sim = 1)
  #sim1 = Sim(object = out.mle, n.ahead = 20L, n.sim = 1000L, par = out.mle$par, n.burnin = 500L)
  #----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  #MARGIN: for a matrix 1 indicates rows, 2 indicates columns, c(1, 2) indicates rows and columns. 
  ret = t(apply(sim$draw, MARGIN = 2,FUN = cumsum))
  VaR = matrix(0,20,1)#1,5,10,20 days
  VaR[1,1] = quantile(ret[,1],probs = c(0.01)) # daily 
  VaR[2,1] = quantile(ret[,5],probs = c(0.01)) # weekly 
  VaR[3,1] = quantile(ret[,20],probs = c(0.01)) # monthly
  VaR[4,1] = quantile(ret[,60],probs = c(0.01)) # quarterly 
  VaR[5,1] = quantile(ret[,250],probs = c(0.01)) # yearly
  VaR[6,1] = quantile(ret[,1],probs = c(0.05)) # daily
  VaR[7,1] = quantile(ret[,5],probs = c(0.05)) # weekly
  VaR[8,1] = quantile(ret[,20],probs = c(0.05)) # monthly
  VaR[9,1] = quantile(ret[,60],probs = c(0.05)) # quarterly
  VaR[10,1] = quantile(ret[,250],probs = c(0.05)) # yearly


  #for day ahead return
  VaR[11,1] = quantile(sim$draw[1,],probs = c(0.01)) 
  VaR[12,1] = quantile(sim$draw[5,],probs = c(0.01)) 
  VaR[13,1] = quantile(sim$draw[20,],probs = c(0.01)) 
  VaR[14,1] = quantile(sim$draw[60,],probs = c(0.01))
  VaR[15,1] = quantile(sim$draw[250,],probs = c(0.01))
  VaR[16,1] = quantile(sim$draw[1,],probs = c(0.05)) 
  VaR[17,1] = quantile(sim$draw[5,],probs = c(0.05)) 
  VaR[18,1] = quantile(sim$draw[20,],probs = c(0.05)) 
  VaR[19,1] = quantile(sim$draw[60,],probs = c(0.05))
  VaR[20,1] = quantile(sim$draw[250,],probs = c(0.05))
  VaR
  #print(VaR)
  #set.seed(123)
  #risk.mle = MSGARCH::risk(out.bay, level = c(0.95), ES = FALSE,
  #                         do.its = FALSE)
  #risk.mle$VaR
}
```

When running the loop it displays this error and I cant figure out the reason as this only happens when there is a high number of iterations in the loop :

> Error in { : 
>       `task 190 failed - "matrix multiplication: inverse of singular matrix; suggest to use solve() instead"

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly due to the new implementation of the adaptive Sampler in Rcpp that we have recently pushed to the github version. We haven't done large scale testing yet but this error seems to come from the correction of the covariance matrix when we detect that it is not semi-definite positive during the adaptation step. We correct the negative eigenvalue to a small positive number to reconstruct a semi-definite positive matrix but seems that it sometimes fail. We will try to fix this error thanks.

In the meantime, could you write an issue at https://github.com/keblu/MSGARCH/issues such that it's more simple for us to track bug.

Also, the CRAN version still use the R implementation of the adaptive sampler so you can use that.

Thanks.